# Optimize a subsetting based on a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm

I am currently working on a dataframe. I am interrested in a column called: "PP_associated"
Each value of a row is a list of dictionnaries. I am interrested in a value that is accessed through a key called: "country". Based on this value, I am storing the rows in an empty dataframe. My code is doing exactly what I want but **I wish to know if I could improve it by using a .loc[] method for performance or another trick.***

The dataframe `wip_r` looks like this:

```
data = [
[first_name, last_name, age, PP_associated, length_associated_PP],
[Charles, George, 74, [{"first_name": "Marie", "last_name": "Antoinette", "country": "FRA"}, {"first_name": "Albert", "last_name": "de Monaco", "country": "MCO"}], 2]
]
wip_r = pd.DataFrame(data=[data[1]], columns=data[0])
```

The current code is as follow:

```
PP_risk = pd.DataFrame()

for i in wip_r.index:
  for j in range(
    0,
    wip_r['length_associated_PP'][i]
  ):
    if wip_r['PP_associated'][i][j]['country'] == 'FRA':
      pass

    else:
      PP_risk = pd.concat(
          [PP_risk,
           wip_r.loc[
              [i]
          ]],
          sort=False
      )
      break
```

To add precision, the column "length_associated_PP" is built by looking at the length of the list of dictionnaries of each row in another for loop earlier in the jupyter notebook. This is also something that feels very heavy to compute and can be avoided ?

I wrote that code, it works well but I don't think it's scalable for production

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of `wip_r`.

Comment: @mozway: it's done now!

Comment: Can you also describe the expected logic? Looks like your code is just making a copy of the input if the dictionary contains at least one non-FRA country. Is this the desired logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code if looping over the rows, then the dictionaries in `PP_associated`, if there is at least one non-FRA country, it keeps the row.

You could then use:

```
PP_risk = wip_r.loc[[any(d['country']!='FRA' for d in l)
                     for l in wip_r['PP_associated']]]
```

To filter based on a list/set of countries:

```
S = {'FRA', 'XXX'}

PP_risk = wip_r.loc[[any(d['country'] not in S for d in l) 
                     for l in wip_r['PP_associated']]]
```

Output:

```
  first_name last_name  age                                                                                                                                 PP_associated  length_associated_PP
0    Charles    George   74  [{'first_name': 'Marie', 'last_name': 'Antoinette', 'country': 'FRA'}, {'first_name': 'Albert', 'last_name': 'de Monaco', 'country': 'MCO'}]                     2
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you think it would be feasible to check in a list of countries instead of only 'FRA'. On the model of isin() ?

Comment: Sure, replace `d['country']!='FRA'` with `d['country'] not in S` where `S` is a set of the countries (`S = {'FRA', 'XXX'}`)