# Replacing values in dataframe in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have asked a question a few days ago that introduce me into an optimized-Pythonic-way logic that is amazing: [Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76711187/optimize-a-subsetting-based-on-a-condition-in-pandas)

I have tried to reuse it for another purpose and I am getting an error code. I am trying to extract values contained in a column where each row is a list of dictionnaries. I am interrested in a value that can be accessed with the key: "ibans"

The dataframe `wip_r` looks like this:

```
data = [
['first_name', 'last_name', 'B.ibans'],
['Charles', 'George', [{"id": "54214312", "bic": "ABC", "ibans": "UK421"}]]
]
wip_r = pd.DataFrame(data=[data[1]], columns=data[0])
```

The current non-working code is:

```
wip_r['banking_country'] = [(wip_r['B.ibans'][d]['ibans'] for d in l) for l in wip_r['B.ibans']]
```

It gives the following error code:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Important note: I'm giving a snapshot of a long dataframe and there are a lot of missing values in the column `B.ibans`

Comment: 1- please ensure that your input is valid python, 2- do you always have **one** dictionary per list in "B.ibans"? What happens if there are no "ibans" key? or several?

Comment: I am always having one dictionnary per list in "B.ibans" and there is always an "ibans" key. The only other case is that the row has a "NaN"

Comment: Aren't you missing the row index? It should be wip_r['B.ibans'][l][d]['ibans']

Comment: @Asettisriharsha the issue is that nans will break the logic

Comment: I have said something incorrect. I have a few cases where there are two or three dictionnaries. In this case, I intend to extract the three ibans and put them in a list. Do you think it's manageable ?

Comment: @Hugoz13 yes it is, but please make sure to provide a valid example with all possibilities (NaN, one, several dicts). See my updated answer.

Comment: you are using nested for loop iterating the element itself instead of index, so you should use wip_r['banking_country'] = [[d['ibans'] for d in l for l in wip_r['B.ibans']]]
I have added another list over it so it works for multiple dicitionaries as well.
You can add if conditions to handle NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the first 'iban' value in the list for each row, you could use a generator with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
wip_r['banking_country'] = [next((d['ibans'] for d in l if 'ibans' in d), None)
                            for l in wip_r['B.ibans']]
```

If you always have zero or one dictionary within the list, then use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
wip_r['banking_country'] = wip_r['B.ibans'].str[0].str['ibans']
```

Output:

```
  first_name last_name                                            B.ibans banking_country
0    Charles    George  [{'id': '54214312', 'bic': 'ABC', 'ibans': 'UK...           UK421
```

##### handling NaNs and multiple dictionaries

```
wip_r['banking_country'] = [[d['ibans'] for d in l if 'ibans' in d]
                            if isinstance(l, list) else float('nan')
                            for l in wip_r['B.ibans']]
```

*NB. replace `isinstance(l, list)` by `hasattr(l, '__iter__')` to handle multiple types of iterables.*

Output:

```
  first_name last_name                                            B.ibans banking_country
0    Charles    George  [{'id': '54214312', 'bic': 'ABC', 'ibans': 'UK...         [UK421]
1   Charles2   George2  [{'id': '54214312', 'bic': 'ABC', 'ibans': 'UK...  [UK421, UK123]
2   Charles3   George3                                                NaN             NaN
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first_name': ['Charles', 'Charles2', 'Charles3'],
                   'last_name': ['George', 'George2', 'George3'],
                   'B.ibans': [[{'id': '54214312', 'bic': 'ABC', 'ibans': 'UK421'}],
                               [{'id': '54214312', 'bic': 'ABC', 'ibans': 'UK421'},
                                {'id': '54214312', 'bic': 'ABC', 'ibans': 'UK123'}],
                               nan],
                   'banking_country': [['UK421'], ['UK421', 'UK123'], nan]}
                 )
```